# Rust MemWriter return pointer to Buffer

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'd like to have a function use a MemWriter to write some bytes and then return a pointer to the buffer. I'm struggling to understand how to use lifetimes in this case. How would I make the below code work and what should I read to fill my knowledge gap here?

```
struct Request<T: Encodable> {
  id: i16,
  e:  T
}

impl <T: Encodable> Request<T> {
  fn serialize<'s>(&'s self) -> io::IoResult<&'s Vec<u8>> {
    let mut writer = io::MemWriter::new();
    try!(writer.write_be_i16(0 as i16));
    let buf = writer.unwrap();
    let size = buf.len();

    let result: io::IoResult<&Vec<u8>> = Ok(&buf);
    result
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of the `Request` type?

Comment: You don't use `self` in this method ?

Comment: I've edited to put the definition in.

Comment: I will use it to write values stored within self but I can't even get this to work yet. I stripped out some complexity before posting my question.

Comment: Does it even matter? How would i write this without self ... So, just a normal function returning a pointer to the buffer after using a MemWriter.

Comment: You can't return a reference to a buffer you don't store internally. Your buffer goes out of scope at the end of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't return a reference to a buffer that is stored nowhere**

You need to store your buffer internally, or you would try to return a reference to freed memory, which is dangerous and thus forbidden by the lifetime checker.

For example like this :

```
struct Request<T: Encodable> {
  buf: Vec<u8>
}

impl <T: Encodable> Request<T> {
  fn serialize<'s>(&'s mut self) -> io::IoResult<&'s Vec<u8>> {           //'
    let mut writer = io::MemWriter::new();
    try!(writer.write_be_i16(0 as i16));
    self.buf = writer.unwrap();
    let size = self.buf.len();

    let result: io::IoResult<&Vec<u8>> = Ok(&self.buf);
    result
  }
}
```

Or, as **Vladimir Matveev** pointed out in the comments, you can simply return the `Vec`. `Vec` is already a container safely managing memory on the heap, returning it directly should be good for you in most situations, and this way you avoid any lifetime issues.

```
impl <T: Encodable> Request<T> {
  fn serialize(&mut self) -> io::IoResult<Vec<u8>> {
    let mut writer = io::MemWriter::new();
    try!(writer.write_be_i16(0 as i16));
    let buf = writer.unwrap();
    let size = buf.len();
    Ok(buf)
  }
}
```

Comment: Encodable is my own made up trait. You can ignore it as it isn't important for my question. Perhaps I should rename it though... I thought I could allocate memory on the heap and have it out-live the function call. How would I do this with the MemWriter? I don't want to store the buffer in the Request.

Comment: Did you forget to update how you store `buf`? You're putting it in `self`. How do i store the contents of unwrap in a box?

Comment: @Upio oh yeah, sorry for that, I corrected too fast.

Comment: Thanks very much for helping me with this. I'm still limping my way through learning rust.

Comment: @Levans, you *don't need* boxing a `Vec`! You should return just `Vec` if you need to give up its ownership!

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Yeah indeed. As the OP wanted initially to return a reference to a Vec, I just kept going this way, without thinking... Shame on me.

Comment: Ok, this is just very important to stress it out that you do not need to use `Box` unless you *know* why you're doing it. `Vec` itself is just three pointer-sized values, you don't need to box them - it gives nothing but unnecessary allocation and indirection.

Comment: @Upio give a look to Vladimir's comments (and the edit I made to integrate them in my answer), there is wisdom here.